# Making 4 with 4 ones (with a twist!)

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

This puzzle is all about making 4 with 4 ones, but with certain constraints.

Allowed operations:

- $-$ Subtraction
- $-a$ Negation
- $\times$ Multiplication
- $\div$ Division
- $\sqrt{a}$ Square Root
- $\sqrt[b]{a}$ Arbitrary Roots
- $!$ Factorial
- $.\!a$ Decimal
- $.\!\overline{a}$ Recurring decimal

*Note: Arbitrary roots must use 1s.*

**Easy:** Give me four examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition.

**Medium:** Give me two examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition, negation, or factorial.

**Hard:** Give me two examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition and factorial, using only one subtraction and one negation.

(In each of the above cases, do not just circumvent the ban on addition by doing $a -- b$.)

Comment: Request for clarification (see my answer to the "hard" question and comments thereunder): 1. Does the "Do not just circumvent this ..." apply to the Medium and Hard questions or only to the Easy one? (I suppose it applies vacuously to the Medium one.) 2.Is it intended to forbid lightly disguised circumventions where $-b$ is, say, multiplied by 1 before subtracting?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes to both.

Comment: Damn. I'll add a note to my answer saying it's invalid according to the intended rules, then.

Comment: Further request for clarification: in the "hard" question, do you mean (1) exactly one sub and one neg *between the two examples*, or (2) exactly one of each *in each example*, or (1') *at most* one of each between the two examples, or (2') *at most* one of each in each example?

Comment: @Gareth Why not just delete it if it's invalid? You can always edit and undelete it later if you come up with some valid solutions.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan 2

Comment: @randal'thor Partly because I feel reluctant to delete something for being "invalid on a technicality", partly because I referred to it in comments above (though only as motivation), partly because I prefer to leave my mistakes on public view :-). I guess deletion probably is best, but it feels kinda weird.

Comment: That extra one tagged on at the end seems to be a very different puzzle; the constraints, set of allowed operations, and destination number are all completely different. I suggest you post it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 7):

> Give me four examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition.

1. > $(1\div0.1)-(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!=10-(\sqrt{9})!=10-6=4$
2. > $-(-\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{11}}-1)=-(-\sqrt{9}-1)=-(-4)=4$
3. > $(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!\times(1-\sqrt{0.\bar{1}})=(\sqrt{9})!\times(1-\tfrac{1}{3})=6\times\tfrac{2}{3}=4$ (thanks @elias)
4. > $(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!-1-1=(\sqrt{9})!-2=6-2=4$ (thanks @elias)

> Give me two examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition, negation, or factorial.

1. > $(1-0.\bar{1})\div(\sqrt{0.\bar{1}}-0.\bar{1})=\tfrac{8}{9}\div\tfrac{2}{9}=4$

Comment: I used one of yours. I hope thats ok!

Comment: @AllanCao Of course!

Answer (score 5):

A concept for the last question,

> $(1\div1\%)+\sqrt[{\sqrt{0.\bar{1}}}](1\div\sqrt{0.\bar{1}})! = 100 + 6^3= 316$

I know I used 5 ones. Can't think of a way to reduce it yet.

Comment: You are actually correct, because you can use arbitrary index radicals. You don't need to use a `1` for it.

Comment: Awarded the bounty to you since you've come the closest to Medium.

Comment: @Marius whoa, what? Are you saying (and do we have the OP's sanction for saying) that we can put anything in the index of a radical (1) even if it isn't made out of 1s and (2) no matter how many 1s it uses? Surely that can't be the intent.

Comment: I was saying that but I got corrected by the op. I was wrong

Answer (score 4):

Easy no.1.:

> $\Big(\sqrt{\frac{1}{.\overline{1}}}\Big)!\times\Big(1-\sqrt{.\overline{1}}\Big)=\Big(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac19}}\Big)!\times\Big(1-\sqrt{\frac19}\Big)=\big(\sqrt{9}\big)!\times\Big(1-\frac13\Big)=3!\times\frac23=6\times\frac23=4$

Easy no.2.:

> $\Big(\sqrt{\frac{1}{.\overline{1}}}\Big)!-1-1=\Big(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac19}}\Big)!-2=\big(\sqrt{9}\big)!-2=3!-2=6-2=4$

An idea towards medium no.1.:

> Using the idea
>  $\sqrt[\frac32]{8}=4$
>  , but I managed to get only
>  $1/.\overline{1}-1=8$
>  and
>  $1/(1-\sqrt{.\overline{1}})=3/2$
> , which contain way too many 1s.

Comment: I incorporated these (crediting you) along with another two in my answer - hope you don't mind!

Comment: Please feel free to do so anytime.

Answer (score 2):

> Give me four examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition.

1. > $(1\div0.1)-(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!=10-(\sqrt{9})!=10-6=4$ (thanks @rand al'thor)
2. > $(-1-1)\times(-1-1)=4$
3. > $(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!\times(1-\sqrt{0.\bar{1}})=(\sqrt{9})!\times(1-\tfrac{1}{3})=6\times\tfrac{2}{3}=4$ (thanks @elias)
4. > $(\sqrt{1\div0.\bar{1}})!-1-1=(\sqrt{9})!-2=6-2=4$ (thanks @elias)

> Give me two examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition, negation, or factorial.

1. > noneuclideanisms caught that this one doesn't work
2. > $(1-0.\bar{1})\div(\sqrt{0.\bar{1}}-0.\bar{1})=\tfrac{8}{9}\div\tfrac{2}{9}=4$ (Thanks @rand al'thor)

> Give me two examples of making 4 with 4 ones without addition and factorial, using only one subtraction and one negation.

1. > Work in progress

> Make 316 with 4 ones.

1. > Work in progress

Work in progress!

Answer (score 2):

Extra question to make 316 from four ones:

> $$(\sqrt{.1})/(.1*.1*.1)$$

Comment: Nice solution, but I need an exact result.

Comment: Exact result? It gets a decimal of around 316

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but I get 243 from this?

Comment: The answer is exactly 316 with no decimal.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy** 4 with 4 ones with out addition

> $(-1-1) \times (-1-1)$
>  $\sqrt{\frac{1}{.\bar1}}! - 1 - 1$
>  $\sqrt{\frac{1}{.\bar1}}! \times  (1- \sqrt{.\bar1}) $
>  $\frac{-1}{-.1-.1} - 1$

**Medium:** 4 with 4 ones without addition, negation, or factorial.

> $\sqrt[\frac{3}{2}]{\frac{1}{.1}-1 - 1}$
>  $\sqrt[\frac{3}{2}]{\frac{1}{.\bar{1}}-1} \times 1$

**Hard:** 4 with 4 ones without addition and factorial, using only one subtraction and one negation.

> $\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]{-1-1} \times 1 \times 1$  (same as the easy one)
>  $\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]{-1-1} \times 1 \div 1$  (I guess easy is the new hard)

**Legend** 316  with 4 ones.

> $\sqrt[\frac{1}{3}]{(\sqrt{1\div.\bar{1}})!} + 1 \div 1\% = \sqrt[\frac{1}{3}]{(\sqrt{9})!} + 100 = 6^3 + 100 = 316$

Comment: To my understanding you're not allowed to do $\sqrt[b]{a}$ with arbitrary $b$, you have to produce them from ones as well.

Comment: @elias. I'm not challenging this, but can you point me where this says so? I think I missed it.

Comment: I can't see it written, but if it was allowed, any $x\gt0,x\ne1$ could be produced from a single 1 as $\sqrt[y]{.1}$ with a well-chosen $y=-\frac{1}{log_{10}{x}}$, which would make the question uninteresting.

Comment: Elias is correct, arbitrary roots use up 1s.

Answer (score 1):

Eas  <del>y</del>   **ier**:  
Make $4$ with  <del>4</del>  **3**
ones without addition.

> $\require{begingroup}\begingroup \displaystyle\kern4em{}\def \@ #1{\sqrt{ #1 \small\raise2.9ex\, }}{}           { -1 - \@    { .\overline1  } \, \over -\@    { .\overline1  }  }{}   ~~ = ~~ { -1 -  \sqrt{   \tfrac  19 }  \, \over -\sqrt{   \tfrac  19 }  }{}   ~~ = ~~ { -1 -            \tfrac 13     \, \over          -\tfrac 13    }{}   ~~ = ~~ {                 -\tfrac43      \, \over          -\tfrac13 \, }{}~~\equiv~~ ~ 4{}\endgroup$